# Safari & Twitter bootstrap & button's loading state

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I am trying to use bootstrap's loading state change (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-stateful) to disable button upon clicking - to prevent multiple submits on client side (on server side, I got this covered). This is the code that I am testing it with.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<form action = "http://slowLoadingPage/">
<button type = "button">This one works well</button>
<button type = "submit">Submit me!</button>
</form>

<script type = "text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('body').on("click", "button", function(e) {
        $(this).button("loading");
    });
  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It works like a charm in FF and Chrome however in Safari, clicking on the button will trigger submitting the form however it will not change the state (class `disabled` is added however state `disabled` is not).

Is there any way to make this work in Safari, please?

Thank you!

**EDIT 1**

Decided to change the JS a bit, instead of watching for click events, I added submit event to form (to catch other ways of submitting form as well). The code now looks as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<form action = "http://localhost/test.php">
<input type = "text" />
<button class = "btn btn-default" type = "submit">Submit me!</button>
</form>

<script type = "text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("form:not([data-loading-state=disabled])").submit(function() {
        setTimeout($.proxy(function () {
            var inputs = $(this).find(":input");
            inputs.attr("data-form-disabled", 1);
            inputs.prop("disabled", true);
            inputs.addClass("disabled");
            $(this).find("button, input[type=submit]").each(function (i, el){
                func  = $(el).is('input') ? 'val' : 'html';
                $(el).attr("data-loading-text", $(el)[func]());
                $(el)[func]("Loading...");
            });
        }, this), 0);
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Again, it works perfectly in FF and Chrome (inputs are disabled and button's text changes upon clicking on the button). **However in Safari**, it doesnt work as good - inputs are "disabled" but they do not look disabled and button's text does not change. I tried to recreate this on jsfiddle but submitting forms doesnt work well there so I created a demo on my own website = http://demo.jacon.cz/test.html. Upon clicking on the button in FF and Chrome, button's text will change to `loading...` and after 3 secs, the form will get submitted. In Safari, it doesn't work.

Comment: [This feature is deprecated!](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/fce30b57e2fbe750cdebf1794d3917f3176d06ce) I recommend not using it. Just toggle the text/disabledness yourself using trivial jQuery.

Comment: Thank you @cvrebert, for pointing that out. However it does not work in Safari even when I use pure jquery:

    `<script type = "text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('body').on("click", "button", function(e) {
            setTimeout($.proxy(function () {
              $(this).attr("disabled", true);
              $(this).addClass("disabled");
              $(this).text("Loading...");
            }, this), 0);
        });
      });
    </script>`

Comment: Why are you using `setTimeout`? And you might want `prop` instead of `attr`.

Comment: @cvrebert changed `attr` to `prop`, it's still not working correctly in Safari. I am using setTimeout because I need to _"push to event loop to allow forms to submit"_ (quote from bootstrap's code). Without this part, it _works_ in Safari (and same way in FF and Chrome) - the button will get disabled however the form will never get submitted (see https://jsfiddle.net/qq6rgt7r/). 
I believe that the setTimeout part there is to allow the button to get both disabled and submitted at the same time.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Actually, I did not, sorry :<